# Karma testing a call to a function inside a scope.function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a UploadDocumentCtrl.js where i am accessing a service call to a function inside another function . This outer function is bound to the scope . My problem is i am unable to access the code statements inside this (Code block C) . I want to access the 'flag' variable and check if that is true . Can anyone point me in the correct direction or tell me what i am doing wrong here ? Thanks ..

UploadDocumentsCtrl.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp')
           .controller('UploadDocumentsCtrl', UploadDocumentsCtrl);

    UploadDocumentsCtrl.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$modalInstance', '$window', 'companyService'];

    function UploadDocumentsCtrl($rootScope, $scope, $modalInstance, $window, companyService) {

        $scope.onFileSelect = onFileSelect;
        $scope.buttonDisabled = false;



        function onFileSelect(files) {
            //Can access the code here
            function upload(file) {
            //Can access the code here as well
                companyService.uploadDocuments(file)
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                   // Code block C 
                  // Cannot access any code here or the error code block below
                        $scope.flag = true;
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {                        
                    });
            }

            files.forEach(function (file) {
                file.progress = 0;
                file.percent = 0;

                $scope.filesToUpload.push(file);
                upload(file);
            });            
        }
    }
})();
```

Jasmine test case

```
(function () {
"use strict";
    describe('UploadDocumentsCtrl', function () {
        var scope, companyService,companyControllerFactory;

        beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller , _companyService_) {
                companyService = _companyService_;
                scope = $rootScope.$new();             
                companyControllerFactory = function(){$controller('UploadDocumentsCtrl',
                            {
                                $scope: scope,
                                companyService: _companyService_
                            });
            };
        }));

        describe("onFileSelect", function() {

            it(" Should make the flag to true ", function() {
                var files = [{}];
                companyControllerFactory();
                spyOn(companyService, 'uploadDocuments').and.returnValue({ success: function(){}});
                scope.onFileSelect(files);
                expect(scope.flag).toBe(true);
            });
        });
    });
})();
```

The error i am getting while trying to do the above..

> 1) Should make the flag to true
>        UploadDocumentsCtrl onFileSelect
>        TypeError: companyService.uploadDocuments(...).success(...) is undefined in http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/Users
>        /Documents/fle/Fle/WebApiRole/app/company/UploadDocumentsCtrl.js?f11d5dcacbf2ca1d63778bfa04c582862e325523
>   ( line 31)
>   upload@http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/Users/Documents/fle/Fle/WebApiRole/app/company/UploadDocumentsCtrl
>   .js?f11d5dcacbf2ca1d63778bfa04c582862e325523:31:17
>   onFileSelect/<@http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/Users/Documents/fle/Fle/WebApiRole/app/company/UploadDocum
>   entsCtrl.js?f11d5dcacbf2ca1d63778bfa04c582862e325523:51:17
>   onFileSelect@http://localhost:9876/absoluteC:/Users/Documents/fle/Fle/WebApiRole/app/company/UploadDocumen
>   tsCtrl.js?f11d5dcacbf2ca1d63778bfa04c582862e325523:46:13
>   @http://localhost:9876/base/test/company/UploadDocumentsCtrlSpec.js?c5db561e203bdfae1a6f7509347d3f7032e8f785:35:17

Comment: Seems like companyService.uploadDocuments is not returning a promise.

In any case, in angular, to test promises "synchroneously", you'll also need to trigger a $rootScope.$apply(); to trigger them.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I am using below format to spy service. You can try below option:

```
var deffered = q.defer();
                spyOn(companyService, 'uploadDocuments').and.returnValue(deffered.promise);
                deffered.resolve();
```

And to apply this you will have to use $rootScope.$apply() before assert (i.e. before expect())

Answer (score 0):

Is **companyService** making an `http` call?

If so, you'll need to mock the response with `$httpBackend` and then get to the proper conditions based on the mocked response using `$httpBackend.flush()`.